# C# clear draw in paint

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use this.Invalidate(); clear but all clear. I need clear only that I drew earlier.

```
            private void AfyTextBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (afytransparentTextBox.BackColor.A != 255 || afytransparentTextBox.BackColor.B != 255 || afytransparentTextBox.BackColor.G != 255 || afytransparentTextBox.BackColor.R != 255)
            {
                path = RoundedRectangle.Create(1, 1, this.Width - 7, this.Height - 7, 2); // Draw around
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(afytransparentTextBox.BackColor), path);
            }
            else
            {
                //Here I need to clean that I drew earlier.( Draw around)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

**`Graphics.Clear();`**

Comment: Clear clears everything OP asks to clear specific elements it seems

Comment: may be this is what OP is looking out for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923626/undo-button-for-system-drawing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'undraw' from a surface. You have to clear and repaint what you want to appear. It is usually enough to tell the component to repaint itself using the `Invalidate` method. You could have a boolean flag to control whether your temporary overlay box is painted or not.